# Dual Electromagnetic Field Tensor in Terms of the First Maxwell Invariant $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

Two Maxwell invariants are commonly known:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}= \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\;, \;\; \mathcal{G}= \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

where $\tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$.

I'm trying to write $\mathcal{G}$ in terms of $\mathcal{F}$. So far, I've reached:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{G} = \frac{1}{8} F_{\mu \nu} \epsilon^{\mu\nu}\:_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha \beta}
\end{equation}

I've tried to insert some $\delta^\rho_\sigma$ and $\eta^{\rho\sigma}$ to change the indices to try to contract both of the Fs, leading to inconsistencies, like $\mathcal{G}=0$, or simply nowhere. I'd appreciate any help on how to solve this, this including any argument on why this can't be done.

Comment: They’re independent. Only an even number of $\epsilon$’s can be reduced to $\delta$’s.

Comment: If you write them in terms of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$, you can find fields that make each invariant zero but the other nonzero.

Comment: You are absolutely right. There's no way I can write $\mathcal{G} = \mathbf{B} \cdot  \mathbf{E}$ in terms of $\mathcal{F} = \frac{1}{2} ( \mathbf{B}^2 -  \mathbf{E}^2)$, unless both fields are zero. Thanks!

Comment: Also, one invariant is a scalar and the other a pseudoscalar that changes sign when you negate a spatial coordinate.